# richfaces IE10 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: xhtml, richfaces, internet-explorer-10

I have this problem just with IE10 while using richfaces everything works fine but i have this exception:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
framework.pack.js, line 2644 character 1

the line that causes the error is : 
LOG.debug("Hidden JSF state fields: "+Q);

anyone knows why this exception occurs? and what can be the solution of it?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but if it wasn't solved (which I doubt), maybe this helps (step 3 contains details about problem in this topic) - http://ruleoftech.com/2013/patching-richfaces-3-3-3-ajax-js-for-ie9

Quote from the above link:

> You will also need to change or comment the next line in AJAX.js or JSFAJAX.js (richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final\framework\impl\src\main\javascript\ajaxjsf)
>
> Replace (line 2119 in AJAX.js, line 1044 in JFSAJAX.js)
>
> `LOG.debug("Hidden JSF state fields: "+idsSpan);`
>
> to
>
> `LOG.debug("Hidden JSF state fields: ");//+idsSpan);`
>
> Otherwise you get the following error in IE9:
>
> `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
>       For this line 2648 in framework pack:
>       LOG.debug("Hidden JSF state fields: "+Q);`

Comment: Please post the relevant parts here, not only a link.